# MySQL Could not create connection to database server

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

До перезагрузки компьютера всё работало отлично.После перезагрузки netbeans пишет ошибку при компиляции проекта

> SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to
>   database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

NetBeans видит мою БД,таблицы, но ошибку всё равно выбивает. Хотя в WorkBench БД работает отлично,запросы отправляются и принимаются[image]

Вот код с помощью которого подключаюсь к БД

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sys?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "root");
```

jar файл драйвера в проект я добавил
[image: jar файл]

[image: Сервер MySQL]]
[image: Driver JDBC]

Comment: Попробуйте в строке подключения указать 127.0.0.1 вместо localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в службах (Win10) и проверьте запущен ли у вас MySQL сервис.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нет, то запустите и следующее подключение должно быть удачным.

Comment: Процесс был запущен,всё равно netbeans не работает